# How to set mariadb read_write for some specific tables while starting as read_only=1

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, read-only-database

I am trying to set a mariadb slave which is exact replica of master db. As per the suggestion I start my slave with command `--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin" "--log-slave-updates=1" "--read-only=1"` . But as I use my slave db as a stage server of my website, I need some tables like cache_* writable to make my stage server work perfectly.

Can you please help me if it is possible or not ? If not then is there any workaround for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Turn off `read_only` and hope that no one abuses it (accidentally or deliberately).

Plan B:  Run the 'cache' stuff as some user with `SUPER` so that it can bypass `read_only`.  This seems more secure than Plan A, but opens up other risks.